# SAP - Mac vs Windows setup

Tags: macos, sap-gui

I'm using the SAP GUI for JAVA on a Mac computer. My colleague sent me the information on how to connect:

[image]

However, the Mac UI looks completely different:

[image]

Where can I find the screen to add a connection like on Windows? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, you need to use the Advanced settings of SAP GUI for Java on the Mac to connect. Go to Advanced and check Expert mode.

Then enter your connection string as:

```
conn=/H/<saprouter>/W/<saprouter password>/H/<host>/S/<port like 3270>
```

In your example I'm guessing:

```
conn=/M/<host>/G/<group like SPACE>
```

You may need to add the service number like:

```
conn=/M/<host>/S/<service number like 4201>/G/<group like SPACE>
```

Comment: The "service number" actually is the TCP or UDP port for the network service. You CAN use the Advanced/Expert mode, but you don't need to, of course. Having a correctly maintained etc/services file will provide the port numbers to the SAP GUI (and all other programs), so that you only need to specify the 3-letter SAP system ID for this in the UI.

Comment: @Trixx: Cool. Never tried using etc/services on my Mac. Always been using the expert mode, but most often to an application server and not the message server.

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague has sent you a screenshot from the SAP GUI for Windows, not from the SAP GUI for Java (which would also run on Windows, but the SAP GUI for Windows doesn't run on Mac OS, of course).
Obviously the screens for both SAP GUIs are slightly different.
But you already found the screen for creating a new connection.
I don't see what is your issue here with interpreting and transferring the logon data from one screen to the other? The field labels are nearly the same.

Comment: Ofc he sent a screenshot from the SAP GUI for Windows, not from the SAP GUI for Java, that's the point of the question... They are similar, however I cannot replicate the settings, as all of the drop-down menus only contain 'none'. So I'm obviously doing something wrong, that's why I'd need someone to help. Also, he has a drop-down list for systems, and I don't (the only thing on the list is 'none'). So again, how can I replicate the settings from the Windows GUI on the JAVA(Mac) GUI?

Comment: What your colleague is seeing in his drop down lists is read from specific local configuration files. Either the IT department will provide you with similar files for your Java GUI or you create them manually by entering one system after another into your Java GUI screens. What I recommend to do is at least to copy the sapms<SID> port entries with a text editor from your colleagues' <WinDir>\system32\drivers\etc\services file and add them into your etc/services file.